# Failed to pip install georasters in MacOSX

Tags: pip

It always failed to pip install georasters in my macbook.
The following is the Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 412, in run_egg_info
    self.setup_py, self.name,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

pip --version:
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: Try upgrading setuptools using `sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: Are you sure that this is happening during the setup for `georasters`? It might be happening for a dependancy.

Comment: You can also try rolling back your `setuptools` using this command: `sudo pip install setuptools==33.1.1`. To get back to the latest, just do `sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools`.

Comment: Thank you very much @GregSchmit. After I tried 'sudo pip install setuptools==33.1.1', the exception changed to '
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-JOFFoc/GDAL/'. Now I am trying to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After many times trying, I resolved the problem.
I used the command:`pip install --no-deps georasters`

```
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#installation-order[enter image description here][1]
```